# Question about differentation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I can't understand a passage: given $f\in C^2([a,b]\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$), $f=f(x,u,\xi)$, $u \in C^2[a,b]$, we have

$\frac{d}{dx}[f(x,u,u')-u'f_\xi(x,u,u')] = f_x(x,u,u') + u'\Big[f_u(x,u,u')-\dfrac{d}{dx}[f_\xi(x,u,u')]\Big]$

I don't understand why, I thought:

$\frac{d}{dx}[f(x,u,u')-u'f_\xi(x,u,u')] = f_x(x,u,u') -u''f_\xi(x,u,u') - u'\dfrac{d}{dx}[f_\xi(x,u,u')]$

Where am I wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the intermediate steps, I don't know why you obtained a different result. In any case, the first equality is correct. Indeed we have that
$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dx}[f(x,u,u')-u'f_\xi(x,u,u')]&=\dfrac{d}{dx}[f(x,u,u')]-
u''f_\xi(x,u,u')-u'\dfrac{d}{dx}[f_\xi(x,u,u')]\\
&=\left(f_x(x,u,u')+f_u(x,u,u')u'+f_\xi(x,u,u')u''\right)\\
&\qquad-
u''f_\xi(x,u,u')-u'\dfrac{d}{dx}[f_\xi(x,u,u')]\\
&= f_x(x,u,u') + u'\Big[f_u(x,u,u')-\dfrac{d}{dx}[f_\xi(x,u,u')]\Big].
\end{align}$$

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank u for the time you dedicated to answer me. Furthermore, I didn't think about continuing the derivation,  that was my mistake, the first equation was of the book, the second one my attempt to solve. Thank you.

Comment: @FrancescoMengoli You are welcome!